# Matan Torah: Coercion or out of love?

Tags: midrash, maseches-shabbos, parashas-yisro, har-sinai

There is a Midrashic approach to "and they stood at the foot of the mountain" [(Shemos 19:17)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.88a.5?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&p2=Exodus.19.17&ven2=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe2=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang2=bi&aliyot2=0&w2=all&lang3=en), namely that G-d literally held the mountain over the heads of B'nei Yisrael, coercing them to accept the Torah (See for example [Shabbos 88a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.88a.5?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&p2=Exodus.19.17&ven2=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe2=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang2=bi&aliyot2=0&w2=all&lang3=en).

The [Midrash Tanchuma (Noach 3:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.88a.5?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&p2=Exodus.19.17&ven2=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe2=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang2=bi&aliyot2=0&w2=Midrash%20Tanchuma&lang3=en) says:

> The Israelites did not accept the Torah until the Holy One, blessed be He, arched the mountain over them like a vessel, as it is said: And they stood beneath the mountain (Exod. 19:17). R. Dimi the son of Hama stated that the Holy One, blessed be He, told Israel: If you accept the Torah, well and good; but if not, your grave will be there.

In Toras Avigdor by Rav Avigdor Miller (Parashas Yisro, p. 108) it says on the concept of *"na'aseh v'nishma"*:

> It means they accepted everything beforehand, before they even knew what would be expected of them. If Hashem would tell them to stand on their heads every morning for ten minutes, they would do it.

Saying na'aseh v'nishma, B'nei Yisrael is praised, because we wanted to fulfill G-ds mitzvot even before He told us to do it. However, the teaching of the Gemara and Midrash, that we were coerced, seems to contradict this. First of all, the pasuk never says G-d held the mountain over the heads.  Similary, the [Or HaChaim](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.19.17?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=Or%20HaChaim&lang2=en) teaches us the opposite:

> ויוצא משה את העם, Moses lead out the people, etc. Perhaps this was necessary because the people had become afraid of the Mountain by now. Moses took them to the edge of the Mountain so that they would accept the Torah while standing there.

The Gemara further states:

> If you accept the Torah, excellent, and if not, there will be your burial.

If you ask me, if someone was treathing me to do something, and I knew it was a case of life and death, I am sure what I did. How then is this considered as "na'aseh v'nishma"? How is this considered voluntarely?

Thanks to Joel K. for pointing out the [Tosfos](https://dafyomi.co.il/shabbos/tosfos/sh-ts-088.htm) on this Gemara. The Tosfos explains:

> Answer (R. Tam): [Both of those] were based on Hash-m's command. It is as if they were coerced. However, in the days of Achashverosh, they willingly accepted [Torah] due to love of the miracle.

The point is, Matan Torah is such an important date in our history. Why then can it teach us that we accepted G-ds Torah only out of "fear" (coercion) and only until Purim out of love?

See also the [Rashba on Shabbos 88a:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.88a.5?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=Rashba&lang2=en) which explains (cited by [Steinsaltz](https://steinsaltz.org/daf/shabbat88/)) that "holding the mountain above the heads" alludes to the love G-d showed the people during the exodus out of Mitzrayim, and because of that, they said Naaseh VeNishmah. But this does not apply to the later generations, only to that generation.

**Sources:**

Miller, R. A. (2020). Toras Avigdor, Vol. 2 - Shemos. Judaica Press.

Comment: Isn’t that the whole point of the Gemara in Shabbat? The coercion meant that there was a מודעה רבה לאורייתא until it was accepters voluntarily in the aftermath of the Purim story

Comment: Regarding how this fits with naaseh venishma, see tosafot in shabbat

Comment: I found the Tosfos. However, I find it strange that only until Purim, it was accepted voluntarily. Matan Torah is when we received G-ds Torah. We "entered into the bridal chamber". Then to say this is only because we were coerced, I find that hard to accept.

Comment: 1/2: I've always wondered something related about Adam and Eve's fall from the Garden and the creation of evil being for the sake of free will. Hashem wanted partners who would choose good of their own volition, not slaves with no choice. And so we have free will as we sit here. However, we also know that if we choose evil, we will most likely die sooner in this life, and be erased from existence permanently. So is that really full freedom? Hashem is all powerful, we are not. Power imbalance. If we don't do what He wants, He can erase us, the consequence just gets put off a little longer.

Comment: 2/2: If u compare to a slavermaster and slave, there is also a power imbalance, and the slave also has a choice to do what the slavermaster wants, or not to and be killed or imprisoned. The slavemaster can say "go pick crops for me," but the slave is still free in their mind like we are. "Do I do it? Or do I choose not to and suffer the consequences?" But theyre still a slave.

I think the distinction is Hashem wants us to do good things, slavemasters sometimes want their slaves to do bad things. But there are some similarities. We also have to work for our bread. 

I dont know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually according to Pnimiyut Hatorah (inner/mystical Torah) it was a coercion of love. In Torah Or the Baal HaTanya explains that G-d revealed such a level of love to the Jewish people that we were “forced” to accept it and said Naaseh Venishma. That’s the deeper meaning behind Hashem holding the mountain over our heads, he “hugged” us with his right hand of loving-kindness.

I found an interesting answer to the question al derech hapshat in an early Pirush on Rashi, [Sefer HaGur](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/633930/p/131/t/0.414425759448087351234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c) (דברים ,ע׳ קלא). There by Megillas Ruth he brings in the name of Rabbi Yitzchak Polak, that when Hashem offered the Torah to the Nations there were individuals who did want the Torah but were nullified in the majority. On the other hand by Matan Torah some Jews didn’t want to accept it and were also nullified in the majority. That’s why we find Gerim convert to Judaism and some Jews “convert” away ח״ו; they both come from those minority individuals. The Rov who published the Sefer from Ksav Yad, [Hagaon HaRav Aharon Shapira](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%90%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9F_%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90), suggests this answers Tosafos’ famous question in Maseches Shabbos. How could Sefer HaGur say some Jews didn’t accept the Torah when we find various places where the Pasuk says all (Kol) Jews said Naaseh Venishma? He answers according to the idea that in Halacha (Taz Hilchos Shabbos) Kol is many times defined as “Rubo k’kulo” and perhaps not literally *all* Jews accepted it but were nevertheless nullified in the majority. He continues, Otherwise we can explain the language of Sefer HaGur that the minority was “nullified in the majority” as saying that some individuals nullified (as a verb) their will to the majority of the Jewish people, but did not really accept the Torah wholeheartedly. For *them* G-d placed the mountain on top of our heads.

[image]
[image: ![enter image description here]
[image]

This section from [Maamar Chayav Inish](https://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/toraor/23/98a.htm), Torah Or:

והנה ישראל זכו למתן תורה על ידי יסורים
דגלות מצרים בחומר ובלבנים. והקדימו נעשה לנשמע כי א"א להיות גילוי והמשכה מאור א"ס ב"ה אלא במקום שיש בחי' בטול דוקא (דלכך אור א"ס ב"ה שורה בחכמה דוקא לפי שהיא בחי' בטול כח מ"ה כנודע). וזהו ענין הקדמת נעשה לנשמע שהוא בחי' הבטול שמבטל רצונו מכל וכל כאלו אין לו רצון בפ"ע רק שירצה כל מה שהוא רצון העליון ב"ה וזהו בחי' עבודה ואותו תעבדו. שהעבד אין לו דעה בפ"ע רק את אשר יאמר רבו עושה. וע"י שהקדימו בחי' נעשה שהוא בטול זה יוכל להיות ונשמע דהיינו לקבל הגלוי והאור מאין סוף ברוך הוא. (וזהו שקשרו להם שני כתרים כנגד נעשה ונשמע שהן בחינת שני המדרגות הנ"ל שבכתר הבחי' העליונה נק' קדמונו של עולם כנ"ל. והבחינה השנית נקראת סובב כל עלמין וממלא כל עלמין) אך כדי שיבאו לבחי' בטול זה דהקדמת נעשה לנשמע. שהרי ביציאת מצרים היו עדיין בבחי' קטנות (כמש"ל בד"ה זכור את אשר עשה לך עמלק כו') ואיך יבאו לבחי' בטול גדול כזה הנה לזה היה ענין שכפה עליהם הר כגיגית שהוא בחי' וימינו תחבקני דהיינו התגלות אהבה העליונה מלמעלה על ישראל כמ"ש אהבתי אתכם אמר ה' (ע' בד"ה ועשית בגדי קדש מש"ש בפי' אהבתי אתכם כו') שאהבה זו תחבקני לכנס"י ומקפת אותו מכל צד אפי' לבחי' אחוריים עד שאינו מניחו לפנות ממנו ומוכרח להיו' עומד עמו פב"פ. דהיינו שע"י אהבה עליונה זו נתעורר ג"כ האהבה בנשמות ישראל עד שבאו למעלה ומדרגה שהקדימו נעשה כו' וכמ"ש כמים הפנים לפנים כן לב האדם אל האדם פי' לב האדם העליון הוא מ"ש ועל דמות הכסא דמות כמראה אדם שהוא בחי' רמ"ח מצות עשה דאינון רמ"ח אברים דמלכא. ושס"ה לא תעשה הם שס"ה גידים. אל האדם היינו בחי' אדם שבבי"ע כמ"ש ודמות פניהם פני אדם. הנה הוא כמים הפנים לפנים דהיינו שע"י התגלות אור האהבה מלמעלה בחינת אהבתי אתכם על ידי זה מתעורר גם כן האהבה מלמטה למעלה והוא העלאת כנסת ישראל בכלות הנפש אליו ית' (וכמ"ש משכני אחריך נרוצה כו'). ולכן נק' כנסת ישראל כלה ע"ש כלות הנפש וכמ"ש אחותי כלה מה טבו דדיך מיין כו'. וזהו ענין על כל דבור פרחה נשמתן. שע"י הדבור והגילוי מלמעלה פרחה נשמתן בבחינת בטול לאור א"ס ב"ה. (ועיין מ"ש כיוצא בזה בפרשת לך לך בפי' מארז"ל בשעה שהדבור יוצא מפי הקב"ה חשות. חשות היינו בחי' שתיקה ובטול כו'). וזהו ענין שכפה עליהם הר הוא בחינת אהבה עליונה שנק' הר (כמ"ש במ"א בענין אברהם שקראו הר. ובענין אהרן א' ה"ר ן'). כגיגית שהוא בחי' דבר המקיף סחור כל עלמין שעי"ז נתעורר בהם האהבה (ובזה יתורץ מה שאומרים מקדש עמו ישראל על ידי חופה וקדושין. והקשו למה שינו הסדר להקדים חופה לקדושין. אלא כי החופה הוא בחינת מקיף והוא ענין שכפה עליהם הר כגיגית שזה בחינת התגלות המקיף כנ"ל. ולכן הוצרך להקדים החופה לקדושין שכדי שיבואו לקבלת התורה שהוא בחינת הקדושין הוא על ידי המשכת המקיף תחלה שעל ידי זה באו לבחינת הבטול להקדים נעשה כו'. ואז יוכל להיות ההמשכה והגילוי בחינת התורה כנ"ל). וזהו פירוש מה שאמרז"ל מכאן מודעא רבא לאורייתא. דהיינו שהתעוררות זו בלבם לקבלת התורה בבחי'
מסירת נפש ובטול עד שהקדימו נעשה לנשמע לא היה זה מצדם בבחירה ורצון אשר מעצמם לבד אלא שעל ידי הגילוי מלמעלה דבחי' אהבתי אתכם על ידי זה דוקא נתעורר בהם הרצון והאהבה כו'. ואע"פ כן הדר וקבלוה ברצון גמור בימי אחשורוש. שהיה מסירת נפש בכל ישראל מעצמם שלא ע"י התעוררות מלמעלה בתחלה ע"ד גלוי בחינת וימינו תחבקני.

---

ספר הגור
מאת רבי נפתלי-הירץ טריוויש
בהוצאת מתיבתא דרש"י
המחבר היה דיין בפרנקפורט, פירוש על דרך הפשט על פירוש רש"י לתורה. פירושו יצא לאור, על-ידי הרב אהרן שפירא מפרדס קץ, בני-ברק

Comment: Interesting view. Thank you! Any chance to put in the sources you mentioned?

Comment: You’re welcome, Im adding them. We should *all* (; have a Kabalas HaTorah Besimcha Ubepnimiyus!

Comment: Thank you and +1 for the great answer. Does the Alter Rebbe also explain what "that G-d revealed such a level of love to the Jewish people that we were “forced” to accept it and said Naaseh Venishma." exactly means? What does it means that G-d revealed a level of love?

Comment: Great answer. Since G-d, the Jewish people, and the Torah are one, should the minority of the Jewish people who only nullified their will to the Jewish people, and not to the Torah, still never have converted "away" from the Jewish people because they nullified their will to the Jewish people? Should that count as accepting the Torah also? If you ignore 2nd sentence of this post, then Jews who gave their will to the Jewish people, but not the Torah, could explain someone staying a Jew but not following the Torah, but how can it explain someone not staying a Jew at all?

Comment: Although I admit that's a tricky distinction and from a Torah perspective it may be impossible. But I was thinking in the modern context of Torah non-observant Jews. 

And did the nations do the inverse? Nullified their will to the nations? As in even tho they wanted to accept the Torah, they forwent that desire & chose the maj opinion of the nations instead? Why then would they convert in the future if they cared more about majority opinion of heathens than they cared about the Torah to start with? Why did they chose that over Torah if they didnt have a stronger will for it than for Torah?

Comment: @YehoshuaLevy: Also, great find of "I found an interesting answer to the question al derech hapshat in an early Pirush on Rashi, Sefer HaGur. There by Megillas Ruth he brings in the name of Rabbi Yitzchak Polak" - is it possible to add a source (link) to this, or do you have a hard copy of this Sefer? Thanks!

Comment: @Shmuel I know I’m glad I came across that, I’ve quoted it various times… I have the Sefer. I was looking the other day for it online. I don’t have Otzar, could be it’s there. I can give you the Mechaber’s email if you want o get the sefer, he is the Rov of Pardes Katz, Bnei Brak.

Comment: @YehoshuaLevy: Ah okay, do you have the Hebrew title, then I can look it up on Otzar :)

Comment: ‏@Shmuel  ספר הגור מאת הרב נפתלי הירץ טריוויש, printed & annotated by הגה"צ הרב אהרן שפירא שליט״א

Comment: @Shmuel  Sefer HaGur is printed in 5 volumes, it’s found in the 5th volume (Devarim in the Megillas Ruth section)

Comment: @YehoshuaLevy Thank you. The only one I found is https://tablet.otzar.org/#/b/162741/p/72/t/16520.41442575944808735/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c but do not think it is this one. Nevertheless many thanks for this wonderful answer. I accepted it! Have a wonderful week!

Comment: @Shmuel yes that’s the Sefer! Just it’s volume 5 though.

Comment: @Shmuel it’s there starting from page 131 in Sefer Devarim, thanks to you.

Comment: @Shmuel The link you edited isn’t working for me.

Comment: @YehoshuaLevy It should. Don't know why. If it keeps not working, lets continue this in chat.

Answer (score 3):

**I remember that the Rebbe (R' Menachem Mendel Schneersohn, 7th Chabad Rebbe) taught us that of course the Jews accepted with "na'aseh v'nishma" first. Once we did so, Hashem out of love for us, granted us the level of "servant" in addition, and coerced us as well (by holding the mountain over our heads etc.). Now we had achieved both the levels of voluntary, and involuntary service.**

This is similar to what is said in the Talmud (Babba Kama 87a):

תניא אידך ר' יהודה אומר סומא אין לו בושת וכן היה רבי יהודה פוטרו מכל מצות האמורות בתורה אמר רב שישא בריה דרב אידי מאי טעמא דר' יהודה אמר קרא (דברים ו, א) ואלה המצות החקים והמשפטים כל שישנו במשפטים ישנו במצות וחקים וכל שאינו במשפטים אינו במצות וחקים

The Gemara presents another statement of Rabbi Yehuda. It is taught in another baraita that Rabbi Yehuda says: A blind person does not have, i.e., receive, compensation for humiliation, and so did Rabbi Yehuda exempt a blind person from all mitzvot that are stated in the Torah. Rav Sheisha, son of Rav Idi, said: What is the reasoning of Rabbi Yehuda? The verse states: “And this is the commandment, statutes, and laws” (Deuteronomy 6:1), to teach that anyone who is subject to civil laws is also subject to the commandments and statutes, and anyone who is not subject to civil laws, including a blind person, is also not subject to the commandments and statutes.

אמר רב יוסף מריש הוה אמינא מאן דאמר הלכה כר' יהודה דאמר סומא פטור מן המצות קא עבדינא יומא טבא לרבנן מ"ט דלא מפקדינא וקא עבדינא מצות

Rav Yosef, who was blind, said: At first, I would say: If I hear one who says that the halakha is in accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Yehuda, who says: A blind person is exempt from the mitzvot, then I will host a festive day for the Sages. What is the reason? It is that I am not commanded and nevertheless I perform mitzvot.

והשתא דשמעית להא דר' חנינא דאמר ר' חנינא גדול המצווה ועושה ממי שאינו מצווה ועושה מאן דאמר לי אין הלכה כרבי יהודה עבדינא יומא טבא לרבנן מ"ט דכי מפקדינא אית לי אגרא טפי:

Rav Yosef continues. But now that I heard this statement of Rabbi Ḥanina, as Rabbi Ḥanina says: One who is commanded and performs a mitzva is greater than one who is not commanded and performs it, I say: If I hear one who says to me that the halakha is not in accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Yehuda, then I will host a festive day for the Sages. What is the reason? It is that as I am commanded, I have more reward.

See also Talmud (Kiddushin 31 a).

**The Rebbe uses this path and says that if the Jews only said "na'aseh v'nishma" out of their own love, then we would be missing the greater level of obedience. Hashem out of love for us, coerced us to grant us that opportunity as well.**

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. A great addition to what Yehoshua said. Can you maybe provide a link to where the Rebbe says this?

Comment: I don't hold my opinions or knowledge in high regard, so I preface that I can often be wrong, but when I read the Babba Kama 87a there, it seems to me to be giving examples of doing mitzvahs when commanded, and doing mitzvahs when not commanded. This seems separate from the third category that the Rebbe is writing about, doing mitzvahs when coerced. 

If my wife doesn't obligate me to wash the dishes, but I do it out of service, that's different than doing the dishes because she holds a knife to my throat, which is also different from having a commandment to do it but no knife to my throat.

Comment: So,

Category 1: Commandment but no coercion to do it
Category 2: No commandment, no coercion to do it
Category 3: Commandment and coercion to do it.

And there could be a fourth not mentioned in the answer, no commandment but coercion to do something, although that would not make much logical sense on the surface, however I could see it coming up in complex situations even though I don't know any specific example in Torah where such a situation arises. But as a theoretical category it could exist as well.

Answer (score 2):

The Maharal asks your question in [Gur Aryeh](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.19.17?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.19.17.2&lang2=bi&p3=Gur_Aryeh_on_Shemot.19.17.2&vhe3=Gur_Aryeh,_Machon_Yerushalyim,_1989-1995&lang3=bi) and answers that even though they were willing to accept the Torah, Hashem wanted to show them that Torah is not optional- it is necessary for existence- and as such they did not truly have a choice.

> אבל העיקר הפירוש אשר נראה פשוט, כי כפה עליהם ההר כגיגית לומר 'אם לא תקבלו התורה, שם תהא קבורתכם' (שבת פח.) לומר כי התורה היא הכרחית לקבלה, ואם לא יקבלו התורה – שמה תהא קבורתם. וידוע, כי דברים המוכרחים להיות הם חשובים במעלה יותר, שאי אפשר מבלעדם, ואין קיום לנמצא בזולתם. לכך כפה עליהם ההר כגיגית להודיע מעלת התורה, שאי אפשר מבלעדה כלל. ואם לא היה עושה זה, היו אומרים כי התורה אין הכרחית לעולם, רק ברצון קבלו עליהם, ואם לא קבלו – לא היו צריכין. לכך היה השם יתברך מפתה ומרצה אותם קודם, וכאשר ראו שעיקר נתינתה על ידי כפיית ההר, היו מוכרחים לומר כי נתינתה מוכרחת, שאין להם קיום זולתה. ולכך הביא שם (שבת פח.) על המאמר זה "ויהי ערב ויהי בוקר יום הששי" (בראשית א, לא), ה"א יתרה למה לי, מלמד שהתנה הקב"ה עם מעשה בראשית, שאם לא יקבלו ישראל את התורה יחזור העולם לתוהו ובוהו. וזה המאמר בא לפרש למה כפה עליהם הר כגיגית, לומר כי נתינת התורה היא מוכרחת:

Comment: Thank you, never knew of this Maharal. Could you also translate it? That would be helpful.