# HOW did they re-accept the Torah?

Tags: halacha, parshanut-torah-comment, purim, shavuos

During the story of Purim, the Gemara (https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.88a.5?lang=bi&with=Sheets&lang2=en ) tells us that the Jewish people "re-accepted the Torah during the story of Esther"

Practically, in what way did their observance change?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/135033/27180

Comment: Both the [Chizkuni](https://www.sefaria.org/Chizkuni%2C_Exodus.19.17.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and the [Kedushas Levi](https://www.sefaria.org/Kedushat_Levi%2C_Exodus%2C_Homily_for_Purim.22?vhe=Kedushat_Levi_-_Munkatch_1939&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) write that they accepted the Oral Torah