# Locating a Sfas Emes on the influence of Chanukah

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, purim, chanuka, golus-exile

In addition to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/138422/27180), I am eagerly looking for the location of  a Sfas Emes where he discuss the following concept (parphrased):

> Chanukah and Purim are both Rabbinical festivals. **Chanukah and Purim are מֵאִיר for the galus**

The Sfas Emes seems to be saying that they are illuminating the current galus. In darker days, these festivals are influencing our days with great light.

I have been looking for this Sfas Emes, but nothing showed up unfortunately.

Does anyone know where this can be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A huge thanks to @Dov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/138423/27180), this Sfas Emes can be found [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=59600&st=&pgnum=86&hilite=):

> כי חנוכה ופורים הם מחזיקים אותנו בגלות כי הם מאירים (בגלות) תוך החושך
>
> Because Chanukah and Purim strengthen us - because they illuminate (in exile) in the darkness...

Answer (score 0):

Please see if [Sfas Emes Miketz 9](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefat_Emet%2C_Genesis%2C_Miketz.9?vhe=Sefat_emet,_Piotrk%C3%B3w,_1905-1908&lang=en#:%7E:text=%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A3%20%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9C%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%94%D7%99%27%20%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%A8%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%AA%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C) is something that helps you:

כי חנוכה ופורים הם נסים האחרונים סמוכין לסוף תיקון הכולל שיהי' נגמר במהרה בימינו בעת ביאת הגואל

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not it I guess. But thanks for searching. The Sfas Emes includes the words מֵאִיר  and Galus and that this is why they share a connection.